# How can I tether my phone's network to my pc?

Tags: tethering

I tried the "Android wifi tether" app and "Clockworkmod", both are not working. I am looking for free solution.

I am using LG Optimus Black and is 2.3 root.

I tried the "Android wifi tether". I can enable the "tether" on my phone and its icon change color too but I cannot find anywhere I can connect to this claimed wifi hotspot network in my Windows 7. I opened the Network and Sharing Center and cannot find any possible wifi. Strange enough, my pc doesn't seems to found any wifi.

I tried the "Clockworkmod" app. It works sometimes but most of the time failed. Some days I can connect my phone's network with it and most other days can't. I tried turn off my anti-virus and firewall too. Here is a example log:

```
C:\Program Files\ClockworkMod\Tether
"Local Area Connection 2"
Checking arguments...
Setting IP Address, mask, and gateway.
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection 2" source=static 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2 1
Element not found.
Setting DNS server.
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection 2" 8.8.8.8 index=1
The object is already in the list.
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection 2" 8.8.4.4 index=2
The object is already in the list.
Adding Windows Firewall Exception
netsh firewall set allowedprogram program="C:\Program Files\ClockworkMod\Tether\win32\node.exe" name=Tether
IMPORTANT: Command executed successfully.
However, "netsh firewall" is deprecated;
use "netsh advfirewall firewall" instead.
For more information on using "netsh advfirewall firewall" commands
instead of "netsh firewall", see KB article 947709
at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=121488 .
Ok.
Starting Tether...
C:\Program Files\ClockworkMod\Tether\node-tuntap
opening tun device: null
```

Comment: Does your PC have wifi capability?

Comment: With what you had already tried (i.e. putting your LG Optimus Black on wifi tether mode), have you tried to connect another phone through wifi.  By this you can isolate the problem. If some other phone is able identify LG Optimus Black and connect to Internet through it, it seems the problem lies with your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use share internet on your smartphone to other devices in 3 ways. WIFI HOTSPOT, USB tethering, BLUETOOTH tethering.

1. Connect your phone to your Computer using working USB Cable.
2. Then Go to Settings->Mobile network(Or More)
3. There you will find a option "Hotspot" or "Tethering"
4. Then select "USB tethering".
   After few seconds you can able to connect to internet on your PC.

Likewise you can Use Wifi and also Bluetooth tethering.

See [Official Google documentation about tethering](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en)